# Changing number format resets cell formatting from Arial 9pt. to Calibri 11pt

Tags: microsoft-excel

It seems like any change to the format of a cell changes the font and font size.

My Excel is set up to default to Arial pt 9. If I have a number, say 1,000,000, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to format it to 1,000,000.00, the cell font is changed to Calibri, and the font size is changed to 11.

I have not been able to find any way to turn off this very annoying behavior:

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. For me, the cell stays at Arial 9, doesn't change to Calibri. Can you check in a different workbook?

Answer (score 2):

Home=>Cell Styles

- Scroll down to `Comma`
- Right Click on `Comma`
- Select `Modify`
- Deselect the `Font` option